Inconsistent Page Numbering Behavior in LaTeX Across Versions
I am experiencing an issue with page numbering when compiling an Rnw file using different versions of LaTeX. Here's a summary of the problem:
Older LaTeX Version (MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.6499):

First page: No page number.
Second page: Page number 2.
Last page: Page 18 (landscape orientation).

Newer LaTeX Version (MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.1):

First page: No page number
Second page: No page number
Third page: Page number 2
Last page: Page 18 (It is empty and in portrait orientation, whereas all pages should be in landscape orientation.)

It seems that in the newer version, the first page is considered a cover page and is not taken into account in the page numbering, resulting in discrepancies with the expected page numbering sequence.
I suspect the problem is also related to the {everypage} package, which is now in legacy status.
I aim to achieve consistent page numbering behavior across different LaTeX versions. Ideally, I want the output to match the behavior of the older LaTeX version.
Below is a simplified version of my Rnw file:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.27in, paperheight=11.69in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.72in, bottom=0.75cm, includefoot, heightrounded, footskip=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{everypage}

\setmainfont[Scale=0.878]{Segoe UI}

\definecolor{iblue}{RGB}{43,72,148}

% Define the position of the page number in the right margin
\newcommand{\rightpagenumber}{
  \begin{textblock*}{1in}[1,0](\paperwidth+0.65in,5.55in)
    \rotatebox{90}{\bfseries \color{iblue} \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
  \end{textblock*}
}

% Add the page number to every page except the first one
\newcounter{pagecount}
\AddEverypageHook{
  \stepcounter{pagecount}
  \ifnum\value{pagecount}>1
    \rightpagenumber
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-, landscape, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\hypertarget{page.\thepage}{}}]{report_1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, landscape, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\hypertarget{page.\thepage}{}}]{report_2.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-, landscape, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\hypertarget{page.\thepage}{}}]{report_3.pdf}

\end{document}

All imported PDF documents are copies of the document created using this code:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.27in, paperheight=11.69in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.72in, bottom=0.75cm, includefoot, heightrounded, footskip=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 

\setmainfont[Scale=0.878]{Segoe UI}

% Configure fancyhdr to clear the default footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Clear all header and footer fields
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}

% Custom command to insert Lorem Ipsum paragraphs with blank lines in between
\newcommand{\lipsumwithpar}[2]{%
  \foreach \i in {#1,...,#2} {%
    \lipsum[\i]\vspace{1\baselineskip}
  }%
}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\lipsumwithpar{1}{57} 
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


All the everypage package does on newer kernels is provide a compatibility interface to the new kernel hooks and issue a warning. So it is unlikely to be changing the page numbering. You can test this by compiling without it on a newer kernel. You could also load the package conditionally (though I doubt it would help, as I say). One thing you should do is move hyperref so you load it last (apart from anything you know has to come later). But there is an issue compiling with XeTeX and trying to do this on the first page. There was another question about this recently ....

Since the page numbering you want is actually the default, I don't see any reason to introduce another counter. We can just use the standard page counter, which will produce 1, 2, 3 etc. regardless of how old LaTeX is. It's also not at all uncommon to suppress the page number on the first page. Only a small wrinkle must be ironed out to do this for the first page of an included PDF.
Note that I used Latin Modern as I don't have the font you used. So my last page is 22 rather than 18.
The code uses the fact that we know that every version of LaTeX will somehow get the correct page number into the code for the page style. So if we create the footer there, we'll get the right value regardless. The only problem is to suppress the number on the first page.
We'll use pdfpages to execute a custom command \dynamicnos on every page.
\newcommand\dynamicnos{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \dynamic@nos
}

This isn't very interesting. All it does is suppress the default style and execute \dynamic@nos.
\newcommand\dynamic@nos{%
  \dynamic@empty
}

This might seem weird. All we're doing is executing yet another command, \dynamic@empty. We could go on like this forever, but we're short of time.
\newcommand\dynamic@empty{\global\let\dynamic@nos\rightpagenumber}

The first time this is executed it doesn't typeset anything. All it does is redefine \dynamic@nos. So now we can see that the weirdness had, at least, a purpose. The first time \dynamic@nos is executed, it execute a command which redefines \dynamic@nos. So the second time it is executed, it executes not \dynamic@empty, but \rightpagenumber.
The effect of this is to suppress the number on the first page of the first included PDF and to typeset the number thereafter.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}% contradicts settings below
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.27in, paperheight=11.69in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.72in, bottom=0.75cm, includefoot, heightrounded, footskip=0.2in]{geometry}% contradicts setting above
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{pdflscape}% don't use if all pages should be in landscape mode
\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{iblue}{RGB}{43,72,148}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\dynamic@empty{\global\let\dynamic@nos\rightpagenumber}
\newcommand\dynamic@nos{%
  \dynamic@empty
}
\newcommand\dynamicnos{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \dynamic@nos
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\rightpagenumber}{%
  \begin{textblock*}{1in}[1,0](\paperwidth+0.65in,5.55in)
    \rotatebox{90}{\bfseries \color{iblue} \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
  \end{textblock*}%
}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-, landscape, pagecommand={\dynamicnos\hypertarget{page.\thepage}{}}]{prawf1}
\includepdf[pages=-, landscape, pagecommand={\dynamicnos\hypertarget{page.\thepage}{}}]{prawf1}
\includepdf[pages=-, landscape, pagecommand={\dynamicnos\hypertarget{page.\thepage}{}}]{prawf1}

\end{document}

The last page is no longer empty or in portrait mode. It is just the last page of the last PDF. If you need further pages for non-included content or just want to avoid potential weirdness, configure geometry for the layout you actually want. pdflscape will create a document which is different orientated in different PDF viewers because not all viewers will obey the rotation instructions.
I tried simplify the example accordingly, but realised your settings are contradictory and wasn't sure how best to resolve the inconsistencies. Since you presumably know the layout you want, hopefully you won't have that problem.
You can then drop pdflscape, in addition to everypage. You should also move hyperref to the end of the packages.
